# Node.js: Send data to client before user connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

What is the best and easiest way to send an array from back-end to front-end in node.js?

I want to start my server, do some data crawling and have that data available on client-side before the user opens the website.

For example, is there a way to send data through websockets before any connection event?

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(playlist));
})
```

Comment: If the user has not opened the site so far, how will you know he will open the site? Basically I think, you can't to anything, before the user comes to your site. You could gather your data beforehand, but sending can just be after the client connection is established.

Comment: So basically you want every browser in this world to recieve your data, even if it never opens your site.. Write a virus i guess

Comment: I want the data to be available in my client, just like html structure is available, not having to send lets say 30mb to client only after user connects, and make him wait for that content.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to send data to a website without establish a connection. But you have a couple of options that can help:

1. First byte flush: you can give the impression to the users that they have the data. Soon a connection is establish, the first thing you send is the data. Or the thing you ask is the data. So when you site load the client will have a impression that the data as already there.
2. For some browsers you can create a plugin, like a Chrome Extension, that will enhance the user experience. The problem is the implementation will differ from browser to browser. So you will need to maintain a few implementations.